# Multiprocessing on python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a task which takes about 10 seconds to run on a single core. I had the idea of using parallelization to improve the performance (if I can run 4 instances of the task in ten seconds I will be able to make some smarter decisions).

So finally I write the following code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Process, Queue
from vrp import task
import time

def task_paralela(queue, parameter):
    ret = task(parameter)
    queue.put(ret)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    cores = 4
    parameter = 1
    processes = []
    q = Queue()
    rets = []
    for i in range(cores):
        p = Process(target=task_pararela, args=(q, parameter))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()
    for p in processes:
        ret = q.get() 
        rets.append(ret)
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
    end = time.time()
    total_time = end - start
    print(total_time)
```

And it works, but the time is now near 20 seconds (twice as much). Why is that? Where is my mistake?

Comment: There is no mistake as such that I can see.. Keep in mind that passing arguments will pickle them in the main process, send the pickle over a pipe, and un-pickle them in the child process (exactly the same will happen with passing results back via the Queue). This is a fairly expensive process, so if the objects are large/complicated, this will be a significant source of overhead. The creation of the child process can also be a significant amount of overhead depending on what is being imported. This penalty is only paid once however, so it is good to keep the process for many tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You're importing `Pool` but not using it, so I'd simply restructure your code (and get rid of the `Queue` too):

```py
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool


def task_paralela(parameter):
    # ret = task(parameter)
    # simulate long running task:
    time.sleep(10)
    return parameter * 10


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()

    cores = 4
    parameter = 1

    with Pool(processes=cores) as pool:
        for result in pool.imap_unordered(task_paralela, [1, 2, 3, 4]):
            print(result)

    end = time.time()

    total_time = end - start
    print(total_time)
```

Print:

```
10
20
30
40
10.01758337020874
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a `ProcessPoolExecutor` see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor-example).

Depending on the kind of work the process needs to do, it might be better to use threading or asyncio. Processes aren't cheap to create so unless there is a lot of actual CPU work to be done they might not be the best solution.

If u are sure Processes are the way to go please check out [this site](https://superfastpython.com/processpoolexecutor-in-python/#Step_3_Wait_for_Tasks_to_Complete_Optional) for a great explenation on how to use the ProcessPoolExecutor

Based on your code, something like this migth work:

```
from queue import Queue
from vrp import task
from time import time

def task_paralela(queue: Queue, parameter: int):
    ret = task(parameter)
    queue.put(ret)

def main():
    q = Queue()
    rets = []

    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        params = [(q, i) for i in range(4)]
        futures = [executor.submit(task_paralela, q, i) for q, i in params]  

        for _ in as_completed(futures):
            rets.append(q.get())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time()
    main()
    print(time()-start)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Aaron pointed out it was not a mistake, but a lack of understanding of what python was doing. Now I have read how pickle works and I have found that writing and loading a pickle is fastest than the previous approach. My new code looks like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Process, Queue
from vrp import task
import time
import pickle

def task_paralela(queue, path):
    with open(path, 'rb') as file:
        my_object = pickle.load(file)
    parameter = my_object
    ret = task(parameter)
    queue.put(ret)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    cores = 4
    parameter = 1
    processes = []
    q = Queue()
    rets = []
    nec_pickle = True
    if nec_pickle:
        my_object = parameter
        file_path = 'Pickle/' + "test" + '.pkl'
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
            pickle.dump(my_object, file)
    else:
        file_path = 'Pickle/' + "test" + '.pkl'

    for i in range(cores):
        p = Process(target=task_pararela, args=(q, file_path))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()
    for p in processes:
        ret = q.get() 
        rets.append(ret)
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
    end = time.time()
    total_time = end - start
    print(total_time)
```

And the performance went down from 20 seconds to about 12.5 / 13.